# How do I find which rpm package supplies a file I'm looking for?

Tags: centos, rpm, yum

As an example, I am looking for a `mod_files.sh` file which presumably would come with the `php-devel` package. I guessed that `yum` would install the `mod_files.sh` file with the `php-devel x86_64 5.1.6-23.2.el5_3` package, but the file appears to not to be installed on my filesystem.

How do I find out which package installs a specific file? I'm looking for where I have not necessarily already locally downloaded the package which may include the file that I'm looking for.

I'm using CentOS 5.

Comment: superuser.com___?

Comment: @Grzegorz Good point, I've put in a vote to move.

Comment: here's a better answer: http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/4706/39281

Comment: @SamWatkins that answer will only work if the package that supplies the file you're looking for is already installed on the system. If the package is not installed (as the OP says) then you can't use `rpm`, you need to use `yum`.

Answer (score 284):

This is an old question, but the current answers are incorrect :)

Use **yum whatprovides**, with the absolute path to the file you want (which may be wildcarded). For example:

```
yum whatprovides '*bin/grep'
```

Returns

```
grep-2.5.1-55.el5.x86_64 : The GNU versions of grep pattern matching utilities.
Repo        : base
Matched from:
Filename    : /bin/grep
```

You may prefer the output and speed of the `repoquery` tool, available in the `yum-utils` package.

```
sudo yum install yum-utils
repoquery --whatprovides '*bin/grep'
grep-0:2.5.1-55.el5.x86_64
grep-0:2.5.1-55.el5.x86_64
```

`repoquery` can do other queries such as listing package contents, dependencies, reverse-dependencies, etc.

Answer (score 215):

To know the package owning (or providing) an already installed file:

```
rpm -qf myfilename
```

Comment: this command looks to be more efficient than yum whatprovides--no need to get updates from possibly slow repositories.

Comment: This version also works on non redhat based distro's that still use rpm's such as openSUSE

Comment: It seems to me that `rpm -qf <filename>` is best suited for determining which package provides an installed application (since it may be different than what is in the current  yum repository cache), and `yum whatprovides <filename>` is best suited for determining which package provides a yet-to-be-installed application. Each has their own purpose.

Comment: Furthermore, `yum whatprovides ...` only requires root if the application is a root package (i.e. it resides in `/sbin`). However, `rpm -qf ...` also requires root in order to read rpms from `/sbin`. Therefore, I propose that the root requirements are functionally equivalent for both methods.

Comment: Anyone using this command, please note that you have to use full file path + filename, and not just the file name.

Comment: @StockB Are you sure rpm and dnf do not use exactly the same database of locally installed packages to determine the package that own specific file?

Comment: `[root@localhost ~]# rpm -qf gcc 
error: file /root/gcc: No such file or directory`  | Why it happens like that ?

Comment: rpm -qf is for installed files. Not for which package needs to be installed. How does this answer the question and more than 200 people failed to read the question.

Answer (score 32):

The most popular answer is incomplete:

Since this search will generally be performed only for files from installed packages, **yum whatprovides** is made blisteringly fast by disabling all external repos (the implicit "installed" repo can't be disabled).

```
yum --disablerepo=* whatprovides <file>
```

Comment: In this case, however, the OP is specifically looking for a missing file that was **not installed** on the system, even after installing a package he thought would have it, so he can't use `--disablerepo=*`

Answer (score 5):

You go to http://www.rpmfind.net and search for the file.

You'll get results for a lot of different distros and versions, but quite likely Fedora and/or CentOS will pop up too and you'll know the package name to install with yum

Comment: This website is offline!

Comment: The website does not appear to search for files; only package names with the search term.

Comment: @jww Searching for files works fine for me at least. As the docs says, you can search for executables by their single path name or any file with the absolute path name.

Answer (score 4):

Well finding the package when you are connected to internet (repository) is easy however when you only have access to RPM packages inside Redhat or Centos DVD (this happens frequently to me when I have to recover a server and I need an application) I recommend using the commands below which is completely independent of internet and repositories. (supposably you have lots of uninstalled packages in a DVD). 
Let's say you have mounted Package folder in ~/cent_os_dvd and you are looking for a package that provides "semanage" then you can run:

```
for file in `find ~/cent_os_dvd/ -iname '*.rpm'`;  do rpm -qlp $file |grep '.*bin/semanage';  if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then echo "is in";echo $file  ; fi;  done
```

Comment: [Don't read lines with `for`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor) and [Why is testing “$?” to see if a command succeeded or not, an anti-pattern?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36313216/why-is-testing-to-see-if-a-command-succeeded-or-not-an-anti-pattern)

Answer (score 4):

Using only the rpm utility, this should work in any OS that has rpm:

```
rpm -q --whatprovides [file name]
```

Ref. https://www.thegeekdiary.com/how-to-find-which-rpm-package-provides-a-specific-file-or-library-in-rhel-centos/

Answer (score 0):

You can do this alike here but with your package. In my case, it was `lsb_release`

Run: `yum whatprovides lsb_release`

Response:

```
redhat-lsb-core-4.1-24.el7.i686 : LSB Core module support
Repo        : rhel-7-server-rpms
Matched from:
Filename    : /usr/bin/lsb_release

redhat-lsb-core-4.1-24.el7.x86_64 : LSB Core module support
Repo        : rhel-7-server-rpms
Matched from:
Filename    : /usr/bin/lsb_release

redhat-lsb-core-4.1-27.el7.i686 : LSB Core module support
Repo        : rhel-7-server-rpms
Matched from:
Filename    : /usr/bin/lsb_release

redhat-lsb-core-4.1-27.el7.x86_64 : LSB Core module support
Repo        : rhel-7-server-rpms
Matched from:
Filename    : /usr/bin/lsb_release`
```

Run to install: `yum install redhat-lsb-core`

**The package name SHOULD be without number and system type so yum packager can choose what is best for him.**

Answer (score 0):

Depending upon whether we know the file path or not we can choose one of the 2 options mentioned below.

- If we know the path of the file then as per the man page for the **RPM** command

  ```
  QUERY OPTIONS
  The general form of an rpm query command is

  rpm {-q|--query} [select-options] [query-options]

  PACKAGE SELECTION OPTIONS:
  PACKAGE_NAME
         Query installed package named PACKAGE_NAME.

  -f, --file FILE
         Query package owning FILE.
  ```

it's pretty straightforward to identify the corresponding RPM package.
For example:

```
[root@e2e-64-147 ~]# rpm -qf /usr/bin/lesspipe.sh
less-458-9.el7.x86_64
```

- If only the file name is known and the path is not, then we can use the **yum** command with **provides** option to identify the corresponding RPM package.
  For example:

  ```
  [root@e2e-64-147 ~]# yum -q provides '*lesspipe.sh*'
  less-458-9.el7.x86_64 : A text file browser similar to more, but better
  Repo        : base
  Matched from:
  Filename    : /usr/bin/lesspipe.sh
  ```