# Valgrind: fatal error: memcheck.h: No such file or directory

Tags: c++, valgrind

We are trying to track down a *Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value* in a C++ project reported by Valgrind. The address provided in the finding is not really helpful because it points to the end of a GCC extended assembly block, and not the actual variable causing the trouble.

According to the <strike>Valgrind's</strike> [Eliminating undefined values with Valgrind, the easy way](https://blog.mozilla.org/nnethercote/2009/02/27/eliminating-undefined-values-with-valgrind-the-easy-way/), we can use `VALGRIND_CHECK_MEM_IS_DEFINED` or `VALGRIND_CHECK_VALUE_IS_DEFINED` after including `<memcheck.h>`. Additionally, those macros or functions are apparently documented in the header file (there is definitely no man page for them).

However, when I include `<memcheck.h>` or `<valgrind/memcheck.h>`, it results in:

> fatal error: memcheck.h: No such file or directory

Based on Stack Overflow's [How do I find which rpm package supplies a file I'm looking for?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1133662/608639), I performed a [RPM file search](http://www.rpmfind.net/linux/rpm2html/search.php?query=memcheck.h&submit=Search), but its returning 0 hits for `memcheck.h`.

***QUESTIONS***

1. The blog article is a bit dated. Does the information still apply?
2. If the information is accurate, then where do I find `memcheck.h`?

---

```
$ uname -a
Linux localhost.localdomain 4.1.4-200.fc22.x86_64 #1 SMP Tue Aug 4 03:22:33 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

$ g++ --version
g++ (GCC) 5.1.1 20150618 (Red Hat 5.1.1-4)
...

$ valgrind --version
valgrind-3.10.1
```

Comment: What does `sudo updatedb; locate memcheck.h` return?

Comment: Did you try  `#include <valgrind/memcheck.h>`?

Comment: @Victor - `locate memcheck.h` returns nothing. I get a new prompt below the command.

Comment: @gsamaras - `#include <valgrind/memcheck.h>` results in the same error.

Answer (score 5):

You have to install the RPM `valgrind-devel` which contains `memcheck.h`.

The `*-devel` packages are typically located in the "optional" repositories (e.g. `rhel-x86_64-server-optional-6` on RHEL 6). Also, you can find the RPM on Google, download it, and install it on its own. With either approach, `memcheck.h` is typically placed in `/usr/include/valgrind` once installed.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @011001000110000101110110011010 The author als asks where to find memcheck.h, which is in the RPM "valgrind-devel" (different from valgrind)

Answer (score 0):

Another way to dig into uninitialised value error with valgrind is to
use the embedded gdbserver.

You can then put breakpoints in your program, and interactively
check the definedness of various addresses/length using various
memcheck monitor commands such as:

```
  check_memory [addressable|defined] <addr> [<len>]
        check that <len> (or 1) bytes at <addr> have the given accessibility
            and outputs a description of <addr>
```

See e.g. http://www.valgrind.org/docs/manual/mc-manual.html#mc-manual.monitor-commands
for more information