# /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -ll

Tags: c, centos, ld

I'm running `make` which passes the following flags to `ld`:

```
LDLIBS=-ll -ldl -lreadline -lcurses
```

However, when running `make`, the linker fails with:

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -ll
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I'm really not sure what shared object library `-ll` is referring to nor sure how to go about figuring it out.

I'm trying this on a CentOS machine, so I tried to install the `'Development Tools'` package, thinking it must be something pretty generic:

```
sudo yum groupinstall 'Development Tools'
```

But with no avail.

Where / what is the library? Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: I believe `libl` (which `-ll` is trying to pull in) is part of Solaris.  Not sure there's a Linux equivalent.

Comment: Are you getting this makefile from some library or project?  `-ll` would suggest something called `libl` is expected, which online searching suggests would be for `lex`.  I don't use CentOS/Redhat, but I'd go for generic build libs, `flex` and/or `bison`.

Comment: It appears that `'Development Tools'` comes with `flex` and `bison`, so those dependencies have already been satisfied. Also, no matches found from `yum whatprovides libl`. Appreciate the input!

Comment: The dependencies can be satisfied, but they must be in the PATH searched by the makefile in order to be found.  I'd check to make sure that the path to libl is either available in that path, modify the path to contain that file, or explicitly path to it.

Comment: what package are you trying to build?

Comment: I'm not really sure what the dependency is for. I'm setting up a project that a friend was developing on. I will look into modifying my `PATH`.

Comment: You can just try removing -ll and see what warnings you get - if any.  The new warnings will be specific missing symbols that are much more informative.

Answer (score 3):

Try re-installing Bison and flex.
`sudo apt-get remove bison flex
sudo apt-get install bison flex`
It worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can find what file is provided by what package using following command:

```
yum whatprovides "filename"
```

Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1133495/how-do-i-find-which-rpm-package-supplies-a-file-im-looking-for) on how to do that

Comment: I did `yum whatprovides l` (because the library would just be called `l`) and got `No matches found`.

Comment: Looks like it is something related to lex http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E36784_01/html/E36873/libl-3lib.html. So you need to install lex/yacc support on your machine

Comment: I believe I did this through `yum`, but thanks for the pointer. I will verify that it actually placed it in a default shared library space visible to `ld`.

Answer (score 0):

TL;DR give `sudo apt-get install libfl-dev`. a shot if you find this questiona and are using ubuntu

---

I got this on ubuntu (on github actions) but wasn't getting it locally.

and from reading a few answers I found out that `libl.a` what is missing, so I tracked it down to this package on my local system.

```
/usr/lib$ dpkg -S /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libl.a
libfl-dev:amd64: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libl.a
```

So I fixed github actions with `sudo apt-get install libfl-dev`.

Locally it says it is a dependency of `flex` which I have.  I am not sure if that is just because I am on the LTS version locally, and using `latest` for CI.

Comment: On Debian, the dependency is libfl-dev is a recommended package for flex, not installed if you use `--no-install-recommends`.