# RedHat, which package provides hdf5.h

Tags: linux, ubuntu, redhat, package-managers

Using RedHat `Linux 2.6.32-504.8.1.el6.x86_64 #1 SMP Fri Dec 19 12:09:25 EST 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`.

I mean to have `hdf5.h`.

In another Ubuntu system `Linux 4.4.0-75-generic #96~14.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Thu Apr 20 11:06:30 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`
I can do

```
$ dpkg -S /usr/include/hdf5.h
libhdf5-openmpi-dev: /usr/include/hdf5.h
```

In RedHat I executed

```
# yum whatprovides "*/hdf5.h"
Loaded plugins: product-id, rhnplugin, security, subscription-manager
This system is receiving updates from RHN Classic or RHN Satellite.
clone-3-rhel-x86_64-server-supplementary-6/filelists                                                           | 931 kB     00:00
clone-3-rhn-tools-rhel-x86_64-server-6/filelists                                                               | 159 kB     00:00
clone-3-ypf-tools-server-6/filelists                                                                           |  61 kB     00:00
clone-rhel-x86_64-server-6/filelists                                                                           |  51 MB     00:04
clone-rhel-x86_64-server-ha-6/filelists                                                                        | 139 kB     00:00
clone-rhel-x86_64-server-optional-6/filelists                                                                  | 2.0 MB     00:00
rhel-x86_64-rhev-mgmt-agent-6-2013-07-05/filelists                                                             |  43 kB     00:00
No Matches found
```

and

```
# repoquery --whatprovides "*/hdf5.h"
```

(no output).

I Googled "redhat which package provides hdf5.h",
and I found https://rpmfind.net/linux/RPM/dag/redhat/el6/x86_64/hdf5-devel-1.8.7-1.el6.rf.x86_64.html
I wonder whether this is correct, and whether there is another alternative, similar to that in Ubuntu, to look for the info at the command line.

**How can I tell which package to install to get the corresponding header under RedHat?**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I find which rpm package supplies a file I'm looking for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1133495/how-do-i-find-which-rpm-package-supplies-a-file-im-looking-for)

Comment: Specifically, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2507087/147356) to that question.

Comment: It looks as if `hdf5` is not packaged for RHEL6. Packages from [Fedora 14](https://archives.fedoraproject.org/pub/archive/fedora/linux/releases/14/Everything/i386/os/Packages/) are generally compatible with RHEL 6 (you would need both `hdf5` and `hdf5-devel`).

Comment: @larsks - I guess they are, given that the package I downloaded is `hdf5-openmpi-devel-1.8.5.patch1-10.el6.i686.rpm`.
See also this related question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48171343/yum-install-complains-about-already-installed-dependency.