# yum install complains about already installed dependency

Tags: installation, redhat, hdf5, yum

I mean to install a package that is apparently not available in my registered repos (see [RedHat, which package provides hdf5.h](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48170542/redhat-which-package-provides-hdf5-h)).

So I downloaded `hdf5-openmpi-devel-1.8.5.patch1-10.el6.i686.rpm` from `rpmfind.net`, and tried installing from file, obtaining complaints about some missing files (see **(1)** below).
But those files exist in my system (see **(2)** below).

**How can I work around this issue to get a functional system?**

---

[This](https://www.centos.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=51975) seems to deal with a related but different issue.

---

Test #1:

```
# yum install /shared/hdf5-openmpi-devel-1.8.5.patch1-10.el6.i686.rpm
Loaded plugins: product-id, rhnplugin, security, subscription-manager
This system is receiving updates from RHN Classic or RHN Satellite.
Setting up Install Process
Examining /shared/hdf5-openmpi-devel-1.8.5.patch1-10.el6.i686.rpm: hdf5-openmpi-devel-1.8.5.patch1-10.el6.i686
Marking /shared/hdf5-openmpi-devel-1.8.5.patch1-10.el6.i686.rpm to be installed
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package hdf5-openmpi-devel.i686 0:1.8.5.patch1-10.el6 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: hdf5-openmpi(x86-32) = 1.8.5.patch1-10.el6 for package: hdf5-openmpi-devel-1.8.5.patch1-10.el6.i686
--> Processing Dependency: libhdf5.so.6 for package: hdf5-openmpi-devel-1.8.5.patch1-10.el6.i686
--> Processing Dependency: libhdf5_fortran.so.6 for package: hdf5-openmpi-devel-1.8.5.patch1-10.el6.i686
--> Processing Dependency: libhdf5_hl.so.6 for package: hdf5-openmpi-devel-1.8.5.patch1-10.el6.i686
--> Processing Dependency: libhdf5hl_fortran.so.6 for package: hdf5-openmpi-devel-1.8.5.patch1-10.el6.i686
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Package: hdf5-openmpi-devel-1.8.5.patch1-10.el6.i686 (/hdf5-openmpi-devel-1.8.5.patch1-10.el6.i686)
           Requires: libhdf5.so.6
Error: Package: hdf5-openmpi-devel-1.8.5.patch1-10.el6.i686 (/hdf5-openmpi-devel-1.8.5.patch1-10.el6.i686)
           Requires: hdf5-openmpi(x86-32) = 1.8.5.patch1-10.el6
Error: Package: hdf5-openmpi-devel-1.8.5.patch1-10.el6.i686 (/hdf5-openmpi-devel-1.8.5.patch1-10.el6.i686)
           Requires: libhdf5_fortran.so.6
Error: Package: hdf5-openmpi-devel-1.8.5.patch1-10.el6.i686 (/hdf5-openmpi-devel-1.8.5.patch1-10.el6.i686)
           Requires: libhdf5_hl.so.6
Error: Package: hdf5-openmpi-devel-1.8.5.patch1-10.el6.i686 (/hdf5-openmpi-devel-1.8.5.patch1-10.el6.i686)
           Requires: libhdf5hl_fortran.so.6
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

Test #2:

```
$ repoquery -l --installed hdf5
/usr/bin/gif2h5
/usr/bin/h52gif
/usr/bin/h5copy
/usr/bin/h5debug
/usr/bin/h5diff
/usr/bin/h5dump
/usr/bin/h5import
/usr/bin/h5jam
/usr/bin/h5ls
/usr/bin/h5mkgrp
/usr/bin/h5perf_serial
/usr/bin/h5repack
/usr/bin/h5repart
/usr/bin/h5stat
/usr/bin/h5unjam
/usr/lib64/libhdf5.so.6
/usr/lib64/libhdf5.so.6.0.4
/usr/lib64/libhdf5_cpp.so.6
/usr/lib64/libhdf5_cpp.so.6.0.4
/usr/lib64/libhdf5_fortran.so.6
/usr/lib64/libhdf5_fortran.so.6.0.4
/usr/lib64/libhdf5_hl.so.6
/usr/lib64/libhdf5_hl.so.6.0.4
/usr/lib64/libhdf5_hl_cpp.so.6
/usr/lib64/libhdf5_hl_cpp.so.6.0.4
/usr/lib64/libhdf5hl_fortran.so.6
/usr/lib64/libhdf5hl_fortran.so.6.0.4
/usr/share/doc/hdf5-1.8.5.patch1
/usr/share/doc/hdf5-1.8.5.patch1/COPYING
/usr/share/doc/hdf5-1.8.5.patch1/HISTORY-1_0-1_8_0_rc3.txt
/usr/share/doc/hdf5-1.8.5.patch1/HISTORY-1_8.txt
/usr/share/doc/hdf5-1.8.5.patch1/MANIFEST
/usr/share/doc/hdf5-1.8.5.patch1/README.txt
/usr/share/doc/hdf5-1.8.5.patch1/RELEASE.txt
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The installed package was a different versión and for a different architecture.
I learned this with

```
$ repoquery -q -f --installed */libhdf5.so*
hdf5-0:1.8.5.patch1-9.el6.x86_64
```

Thus, I downloaded and installed

```
# yum install hdf5-1.8.5.patch1-10.el6.x86_64.rpm
...
# yum install hdf5-openmpi-1.8.5.patch1-10.el6.x86_64.rpm hdf5-openmpi-devel-1.8.5.patch1-10.el6.x86_64.rpm
...
```

and it did not complain.

[This](https://serverfault.com/a/208907/326962) hinted me at the answer.
See also [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/170528/yum-says-dependency-libltdl-so-3-is-required-but-its-already-installed).